# Continuous Flag based on presence on value in group - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to write a query that flags the status of 'Remove from BD' on April 22 per account. Once that occurs, I would for that row to be flagged along with any subsequent rows per account.  I can write a case statement for 'Remove from BD' on April 22, but that will not capture the subsequent rows per account.

Sought output below:

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Be great to see what you tried. And you will most likely get assistance much faster if you provide the sample data as DDL+DML rather than an image.

Comment: Are you looking to persist the flag as an actual column, or just `select` the result with that flag?

Comment: Looking to persist the flag as an actual column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to persist the flag as an actual column, you could consider something like:

```
UPDATE t1
SET flag = CASE WHEN t2.account IS NOT NULL THEN 'X' END
FROM test t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN test t2 
  ON t2.account = t1.account 
   AND t2.transactionpostdate <= t1.transactionpostdate
   AND t2.status = 'Remove From BD'
   AND t2.transactionpostdate = '2022-01-22'
```

This joins the table to itself. If there is no column for the same `account` with a <= `transactionpostdate`, then `t2.account` will be `null`. Therefore `CASE WHEN t2.account IS NOT NULL THEN 'X' END` gives you the flag you want. You can see it [working in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gJFyxfjj).

Having said that, I would recommend *not* persisting this in the table. It depends entirely on other data, so it's redundant information. You could calculate it in your queries, or create a view or calculated column that calculates it. For example, [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/kWbqgaxk) it is being returned without being stored (doesn't waste disk space, you can't accidentally forget to update the column, and the logic can be changed easily in the future):

```
SELECT test.*, CASE WHEN max(CASE WHEN status = 'Remove From BD' and transactionpostdate='2022-04-22' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY transactionpostdate) = 1 THEN 'X' END flag
FROM test
ORDER BY account, transactionpostdate
```

Comment: Looks good, but how do I specify the date clause? 'Remove from BD' + April 22'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the requirement while typing that. I've fixed the post and both examples to include the date condition.

Comment: Thanks so much - but i get an error when adding that clause in he case statement 

'and transactionpostdate='2022-04-22'

Comment: Did you also change the first part of the `case`? Previously I was using the format `CASE status WHEN ...` but I changed that to `CASE WHEN status=...` in order to have a second condition.

Comment: Looks great! it works!.  Last question, if your fiddle, what if I wanted to Flag row 5,

Basically capture all rows, when status = 'Remove From BD' and transactionpostdate='2022-04-22' for each account?

Comment: How do you want to flag it? You want another column returned (second flag), or you want a different flag for that scenario? If the latter, you could do `CASE WHEN  status = 'Remove From BD' and transactionpostdate='2022-04-22' THEN 'Z' WHEN max(CASE WHEN status = 'Remove From BD' and transactionpostdate='2022-04-22' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY transactionpostdate) = 1 THEN 'X' END flag`

Comment: That did not work, Can u please show fiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252883/discussion-between-sirbenson-and-edmcoff).